# Imagick convert adobeRGB to sRGB don't keep colors - PHP

Tags: php, colors, imagemagick, rgb, imagemagick-convert

I have to work with an image with PHP GD. The problem is when I copy the original picture, the colors are not the same.

People told me to convert my jpg into sRGB profil instead AdobeRPG.

So I did it:

```
$image = new Imagick($chemin_image);

// Essayer de mettre en SRGB si ce n'est pas le cas
$icc_srgb = file_get_contents('../../admin-cache/outils/sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled.icc');

$image->setImageProfile('icc' , $icc_srgb);
$image->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);

$image->writeImage($chemin_image);
```

But, this doesn't change anything, my picture still not as original:

[rgb-picture](http://regex.info/exif.cgi?dummy=on&imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fdonnemoifaim.fr%2Fimgs%2Falsacreations%2Fdont-work.jpg)

I went to Facebook, to see, how he does in his own upload system, I tried with my picture and there is the result:

[facebook-conversion](http://regex.info/exif.cgi?dummy=on&imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent-cdg2-1.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fv%2Ft35.0-12%2F15302469_1170918652987061_306690036_o.jpg%3Foh%3D734c90a1bd4ce46a535a71cc9f93722a%26oe%3D58478710#ICC_Profile)

It's work very well, but I have no idea how they have done.

Comment: There is the original picture : http://regex.info/exif.cgi?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fdonnemoifaim.fr%2Fimgs%2Falsacreations%2Fphoto_acceuil_3.jpg

Comment: You write you work with PHP GD, but your code uses ImageMagick. With the latter, for color space conversion you have to use [Imagick::transformImageColorspace](http://php.net/manual/de/imagick.transformimagecolorspace.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can check your image data using this in php and IM V6:

```
system( "identify -verbose bfbf1b7ec569ff2ba4c451d48e9d39d8.jpg" );
```

Looking at your first two photos one was interlaced and the other was not and the quality was slightly different. When you get to the profiles they are different:

> Profiles:
>       Profile-8bim: 62 bytes
>       Profile-icc: 3048 bytes
>       Profile-iptc: 50 bytes
>         Byline[2,80]: DonneMoiFaim
>         Copyright String[2,116]: Copyright2016 , DonneMoiFaim
>
> Profiles:
>       Profile-8bim: 116 bytes
>       Profile-icc: 3048 bytes
>       Profile-iptc: 103 bytes
>         Special Instructions[2,40]: FBMD01000a840d0000d95d0000baa200001cad000070bc0000a8ce00000c290100fa3c0100fc4f0100b966010071110200

But you do not know what the Facebook code is doing; it could be adding some sharpening or some other tweek.

Comment: Ok but my question : how can i get the same image as origin after converting adobeRGB picture into sRGB with PHP ? Nothing I have seen same work, but Facebook success.